# How to synchronize with the test network in Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm beginning with Ethereum Wallet to deploy the smart contracts. I utilize Rinbery testnet to work. Unfortunately, for the moment I don't possess any amount of Ether to deploy the contracts. Then I go to a faucet website (https://faucet.rinkeby.io/) to request some cash. I think that my account contains some cash now by consulting https://rinkeby.etherscan.io. But in the application Ethereum Wallet, my account still has no cash. And I see this message when consulting my account in the app : 
`If your balance doesn't seem updated, make sure that you are in sync with the network.` 
Can someone help to synchronize to the network ?

[image]

Here is what I found on rinkeby.etherscan.io:
[image]

Comment: At the top between "Send" and "Contract" buttons there are a couple of indicators about the synchornization, those appear to be at 0 meaning the synchorization didn't start. Make sure to download a recent version of "Ethereum Wallet".

Comment: When I launch the application, it displays an openning window as you see [here](https://ibb.co/gLZ02S). Will I need to wait until the end of the sync or I can click "LAUNCH APPLICATION" to open the app ?

Comment: Yes, you can launch the application but you will not be able to make a transaction until it has finished syncing, nor consult the updated balances. You can look at your addresses or previous transactions if they were synchronized previously.

Comment: I did let the application launching during hours for syncing but nothing changed. Can you explain how to sync the network that I can see the exact balance of my account in Ethereum Wallet application ?

Comment: If the indicator at the top remain at zero it indicate some kind of network issue, perhaps are you behind a firewall or proxy?. You can try reinstalling Ethereum Wallet (make sure to backup your keys!!). If all else fails you can try running a geth instance from a console to try to determine what is failing.